# CRC Calculation in C

Tags: c, crc

I have a device, which sends me Data with CRC Calculation.
Every 16 Bytes there are 2 CRC Bytes.
The generator polynomial is x16 + x13 + x12 + x11 + x10 + x8 + x6 + x5 + x2 + 1

My code looks like this:

```
int crc16(unsigned char *addr, int num, int crc)
{
    uint16_t poly = 0x3D65;
    int i;
    for (; num > 0; num--)           /* Step through bytes in memory */
    {
        crc = crc ^ ((unsigned short)*addr++ << 8);         /* Fetch byte from memory, XOR into  CRC top byte*/
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)      /* Prepare to rotate 8 bits */
        {
            if (crc & 0x10000)       /* b15 is set... */
                crc = (crc << 1) ^ poly;    /* rotate and XOR with XMODEM polynomic */
            else                     /* b15 is clear... */
                crc <<= 1;           /* just rotate */
        }                            /* Loop for 8 bits */
        crc &= 0xFFFF;               /* Ensure CRC remains 16-bit value */
     }                               /* Loop until num=0 */
     return(crc);                    /* Return updated CRC */
}
```

I've also tried this code with other polynomials like 0x9CB2. I think there's an error located in the code.

Comment: And your question is .... what, exactly?

Comment: Could you elaborate more the question, please? tell us exactly where the problem is...

Comment: Ok, so you think there's an error in the code. But why do you think that? What exactly is it that doesn't work? Which incorrect results do you get?

Comment: Why do you store a byte in a 16 bit and XOR with the ms byte? This seems very strange to me.

Comment: How does the documentation of the device describe the CRC, besides the polynomial?  The CRC bits could be stored in either order, there could be an initial value different from zero, and there could be pre and/or post conditioning.  You should read http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt .

Comment: Can you provide an example of 16 bytes of data and the 2-byte crc from the device?

Comment: Can you get the [online live CRC calculator](http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html) to generate the same CRC as your device?

Answer (score 1):

Which compiler/platform are you using? Are you sure the `int` datatype is 32 bits? Try it with `long` and compare the results.

Also, there is a point in which you make the following if:

```
if ( crc & 0x10000 )
```

and in the comment you state that you are verifying the 15th bit. No, that's not true, you will be verifying the 16th bit. For the 15th it would be `( crc & 0x8000 )`.

Comment: Or simply write `if(crc >> 15)` so it becomes obvious what the code does.

Comment: Yes... and no. I have the impression that the platform in which this code would be executed is a microprocessor in an embedded device. If that's the case, the && is atomic (one CPU cycle). Your proposal, 100% right, but on some hardware it would mean 15 CPU cycles. And if the CPU is 8 bits wide... you can imagine!

Comment: The compiler will most likely be able to optimize the code on such platforms.

Comment: Not likely. I use to program those kind of devices and optimization are usually disabled for a bigger control on time delays and constant execution time.

Comment: Umm... no? I program these kind of systems all the time. Only hobbyists rely on op-code based delay loops, professionals use on-chip hardware timers, so that's not even an issue. As for constant execution time, once you are done touching a source file, the compiler will optimize the code in the same way each time. I just made a test with an old compiler for a 16 bit MCU and it optimized the right shift into a check against 0x8000, just as I expected. 8-bitters are likely to perform poorly on any 16-bit CRC, I would use a lookup table for the CRC in that specific case.

Comment: I suppose we use different development environments. I program 8-bit microprocessors, with low freq. osc. and those optimizations are not always at my disposal. And let me tell you that there are hobbyist that program a lot better than those who pose as real professionals. Professionals AND hobbyist work in C and in assembler, with or without optimization, and are not afraid of doing so. My former comment was constructive, not destructive. I will no comment more on this issue, as it's warming up. This is not the place for that.